# Getting ActiveAdmin paths for any model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

ActiveAdmin generates methods to get the paths of each class. For example, if I wanted to make a link to a `FooBar` object I would call `link_to obj.name, admin_foo_bar_path(obj)`.

How would I do that without needing to hard code the class of the object in `admin_foo_bar_path`?

For example, if I wanted to make a function usable by any class...

```
def show_link(obj)
  display = obj.try(:name) || obj.id
  link_to display, ???
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello such function already exists in active admin 
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/ef4e80ea2f0cb528ea146becd104f7b5b029910d/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/auto_link_helper.rb#L14
example:

```
index do
    column :name, :sortable => :name do |company|
      auto_link(company)
    end
    column :active do |company|
      company.active? ? icon(:check) : icon(:x)
    end
  end
```